# ABP.io angular cannot read property replace of undefined

Tags: c#, .net, angular, abp

I'm using Abp.io for .net backend and angular for frontend, I've the backend up and running and works pretty ok on swagger.
However when I generate proxies for the backend with the command "abp generate-proxy" it throws me an error saying "cannot read property replace of undefined" and that's bout it, I've no clue where to look for errors.
Note I've generated proxies before and I know how they look inside an angular project but after adding more endpoints I keep getting this error, I've also attached a screen shot just in case you want to have a look at it.
I would really appreciate some help, thanks guys.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also received this error. I believe this occurs if there are no models/services to generate. After adding my first model and CrudService the error never re-appeared.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. First there was a JSON serialize in startup file that was causing that error and the frontend project's API address was targeting to the live instead of the local one.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. First there was a JSON serialize in startup file that was causing that error and the frontend project's API address was targeting to the live instead of the local one.